# Maven dependency is imported but still i get a "Unresolved reference" error - Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

[image: Unresolved reference]

[image: My libraries]

As you can see in the pictures I have the maven library successfully imported but i still get this annoying unresolved reference error. I have no idea what the problem is. For me it looks perfectly fine and this is really pissing me off. What the bloody hell is wrong with Intellij. Am i missing something? I hope you can help me.

Edit: I can import the classes in a Java file but not in a Kotlin file

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, i found a solution which works perfectly fine for me. I uninstalled Intellij Ultimate and installed Intellij Community again. With Intellij Community it works fine.

Comment: In my case the problem was in Proguard obfuscation